# How to create a surface from many textures or renderer

Tags: c, sdl-2

I would like to be able to create a bitmap with SDL2.

For this I want to use SDL_SaveBMP.

However, I do not know how to create the SDL_Surface that I need.
I have to save a map created from a lot of textures.

How can I do?

EDIT : this work, but not when I use the function SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer like `SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(0, 0, SDL_WINDOW_MAXIMIZED|SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE, &window, &renderer);` :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SDL_Window *window = NULL;
    SDL_Renderer *renderer = NULL;

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    //window = SDL_CreateWindow("Title", 200, 200, 500, 500, 0);

    SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(500, 500, SDL_WINDOW_MAXIMIZED|SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE, &window, &renderer);

    SDL_Surface *screenshot = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0, 500, 500, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    //SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 60, 10, 255, 255);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

    SDL_RenderReadPixels(renderer, NULL, 0, screenshot->pixels, screenshot->pitch);
    SDL_SaveBMP(screenshot, "screenshot.bmp");

    SDL_FreeSurface(screenshot);

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Either use `SDL_SetRenderTarget` (potentially hardware renderer) or `SDL_CreateSoftwareRenderer` (software renderer).

Comment: I use ```SDL_CreateSoftwareRenderer``` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Come on. How exactly did you use it and how exactly it doesn't work? [mcve] please.

Comment: `format == 32` is suspicious. It's supposed to be [a enum](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PixelFormatEnum)?

Comment: Thanks you so much for your help. The code I wrote at the top works, but not when I use the SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer function.

Comment: Can you share your code that uses `SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer`? Try setting the size to something other than 0,0

Comment: I update the code. If you want, I can give you the code of my projects but there is more than 1000 lines in French.

Comment: Nope, I don't need the full code. Enable your compiler's warnings/strict errors, the code doesn't compile for me: `1.cpp:13:5: error: no matching function for call to 'SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer'` `SDL_render.h:205:29: note: candidate function not viable: cannot convert argument of incomplete type 'SDL_Window *' to 'SDL_Window **' for 4th argument; take the address of the argument with &` (and same applies to `renderer`).

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. That was because I have a function to create window on my project. I made the modifications but it still crash and doesn't take screenshot.

Comment: Your window is maximized, but the surface is not resized to accomodate its size.